# How to append a list of dictionary inside of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, mypy

I have an issue that I am scratching my head over.

I have dictionary as follow:

```py
my_dict = {'key': ['string', [{'id': 'id_value', 'number' : 'number_value'}]]}
```

and in the processing of this dictionary I wanted to append the list at the end.

However, when I do

```py
my_dict['key'][1].append({'id2': 'id_value2', 'number2' : 'number_value2'})
```

I am getting an error from mypy: `error: "object" has no attribute "append"`

What could I do here? The logic seems to be working and I am appending a list after all..

Comment: works fine for me, double check your example. What is the output of `my_dict['key'][1]` and `type(my_dict['key'][1])`

Comment: @mozway `my_dict['key'][1]` outputs `[{'id': 'id_value', 'number' : 'number_value'}]` and `type(my_dict['key'][1])` returns `<class 'list'>`. As I said the functionality is doing what i should but mypy has issue with this.

Comment: I see, then you should use the `mypy` tag, this is what the question is about

Comment: I do have mypy included in my tags..

Comment: Yes because **I added it** ;)

Comment: Haha, okay, didn't know it was you. Thanks :)

Comment: lists are homogenously typed. statically, all elements have the same type, so `'string'` and `[...]` are both treated as `object`, which indeed doesn't have an `append` attribute. Without using a more descriptive type, like a tuple I'm not sure this is doable w/o `# type: ignore`. I can see you might not be able to use a tuple though as that looks like JSON

Comment: It's a json indeed. I've came up with different data types inside of the dictionary, so its all good now :)

Answer (score 0):

to append new key value pair in dictionary use below code

```
my_dict['id2'].append('id_value2')
my_dict['number2'].append('number_value2')
```